# SQL Server 2008 R2. Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Why do i get the following error

```
Incorrect syntax near 'AUTO_INCREMENT'.
```

while trying to execute

```
CREATE TABLE Person
(
    P_Id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name varchar(255),

    PRIMARY KEY (P_Id)
)
```

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: `AUTO_INCREMENT` is MySQL syntax for SQL Server's `identity`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
P_Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
Name varchar(255))
```

You should explicitly state whether `NAME` is `NULL` or `NOT NULL` so you are not dependant upon the [current connection settings that happen to be in effect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187375.aspx).

Comment: Had a issue with 'AUTO_INCREMENT'. Replaced it with 'IDENTITY(1,1)' and it worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
create table Person
(
    PersonId int identity(1,1) 
        constraint PK_Person primary key,
    Name varchar(255) not null
)
```

Some comments:

1. It is not needed to specify `not null` for identity column as identity column cannot be nullable. `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` option does not affect 'nullability' of identity column.
2. On other hand it is important to specify 'not null / null' for Name column, as it will be affected by `ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON` value.
3. It is always a good idea to explicitly specify names for constraints. Because if you don't, name constraint name will be generated. If you need to delete the constraint later, you will have to find out the auto-generated name.